# Suitelet with multiple lists

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am trying to create a Suitelet to display multiple sets of data. I will have 2 saved searches that I want to just display the results like 2 separate windows on one page.

I know that you can display results by using response.writePage(list) where list is a nlobjList. I know that nlobjList can display results of a nlobjSearchResults by just passing it to list.addRows(searchResults).

I tried to do 2 writePage calls with 2 different lists, but as I expected it just displays the second of the 2 calls.

Has anyone done this? How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 3):

Just work with each sublist as if it were the only one and NetSuite will put them on separate tabs for you.

```
function suitelet(request, response) {
    var form = nlapiCreateForm('Test Page');
    var sublist1 = form.addSubList('list1', 'list', 'List 1');
    var sublist2 = form.addSubList('list2', 'list', 'List 2');

    sublist1.addField('custpage_field1', 'text', 'Field1');
    sublist1.addField('custpage_field2', 'text', 'Field2');

    sublist2.addField('custpage_field3', 'text', 'Field3');
    sublist2.addField('custpage_field4', 'text', 'Field4');

    response.writePage(form);
}
```

Results in:
[image]

Comment: That got me part of the way there. The issue I am having now is how to display the results of my search. I saw I can use sublist.setLineItemValues() and pass it an nlobjSearchResult array. I tried that and it didn't work. I tried to therefore ensure I set the fields first - I did 3 calls of sublist.addField() and ensured my data types matched my 3 columns in my results. It now shows 4 rows (correct for my results) but it doesn't show the actual results in those rows. Any ideas?

Comment: If you're going to pass search results to .setLineItemValues(), the field names of your sublist must match the internal IDs of the columns in your search result.  I know that the help documentation says that your column names must start with 'custpage', but that's not always the case.  If you're returning 'trandate' in your search, then have a sublist field named 'trandate' and the values will line up.

Comment: I tried what you said. I realized I left out a detail - I need to have the fields grouped. In my saved search I have them grouped there. When I ungroup, it works fine. How can I display grouped results? –